# Trouble with array-list when storing the file data in the array-list

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to find the difference between two text files and trying to write the diffrence in the third file !!!
I am quite successful to do that but my file is too big it has almost 200000 lines and when I am storing it in to an arrylist it only stores the data till line no 6482 .I dont understand why it is happening. Can anyone please help me with that ?
Here is my code

```
    import java.io.*;


    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SearchThe {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // Open the file c:\test.txt as a buffered reader


                      Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D://abc.txt"));
                      Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File("D://xyz.txt"));
//                       Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D://file1.txt"));
//                      Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File("D://file2.txt"));
                    ArrayList<String> file1_list = new ArrayList() ;
                    ArrayList<String> file2_list = new ArrayList();
//                    file1_list.ensureCapacity(193225);
//                     file2_list.ensureCapacity(193225);
                    while (s.hasNext()) {
                        file1_list.add(s.next());

                    }
                    s.close();
                    while (s2.hasNext()) {
                        file2_list.add(s2.next());
                    }
                    s2.close();
                     FileWriter stream = new FileWriter("D://file1_copy.csv");
                          BufferedWriter abc = new BufferedWriter(stream);
                    for(int i=0;i<file1_list.size();i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("File 1 data" +file1_list.get(i));
                         abc.write(file1_list.get(i));abc.newLine();

                    }
                    abc.close();
//                   

            // Start a line count and declare a string to hold our current 
            int linecount = 0;
                String line;

            // Let the user know what we are searching for

//                      for(int i=0;i<file1_list.size();i++)
//                      {   // Loop through each line, stashing the line into our line     
                         FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("D://result.txt");
                          BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                          for(int j =0;j<file1_list.size();j++)
                          {

                          System.out.println("\n\nSearching for  " + file1_list.get(j) + "  in file 1...");



                           if(file2_list.contains(file1_list.get(j)))
                           {
                               System.out.println(file1_list.get(j) +"   found in a file 2");

                           }
                           else
                           {
                               System.out.println(file1_list.get(j) +"  not found in a file 1 ");
                               out.write(file1_list.get(j));out.newLine();

                           }

                      }
                          out.close();



        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are getting an error, and if you read the error carefully it might indicate a solution esp if you google what that error means.

Comment: I'm seeing 4 files there. You could have at least formatted your code a bit and reduce it to what is relevant to the question. Like, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

By default whitespace delimiter is used by a scanner; are you sure there is whitespace after line No 6482. Please check if the last token has not return the entire File after line No 6482.

In case there is no issue with whitespace delimiter, please check the free memory of java runtime.

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long freeMem = rt.freeMemory();

I hope memory should not be a problem, as for  32-bit process model, the maximum virtual address size of the process is 4 GB approx; but it's better to check.
Hope, it will give you a pointer to your issue.

Comment: I checked the freememory and it says

Comment: ree memory 69476304

so that is not an issue , you were right .And there is a white space after the line 6482 too. I cant figure out whats the problem :(

Comment: It look like Scanner class has some issue with large file, please try with BufferedReader (With FileReader).

Answer (score 0):

I checked the free memory and it says

free memory    69476304

so that is not an issue , you were right .And there is a white space after the line 6482 too.
I cant figure out whats the problem :(